# Query using NLP [PYTHON]

Tags: python, nlp

I'm working on a project where I need to extract "inputs" and "query intent" from text.

For example "What is the status of asset X26TH?"

In this case the main issue is to extract asset id which is X26TH, but how can I make my code understand that it's an id?

The other thing is to understand the query intent which is asset status. I found a good library for this called [quepy](https://github.com/machinalis/quepy), but it's meant for linux and I couldn't set it up on windows.

Please help me with the techniques and libraries.

Comment: Have you used POS tagging? try out Spacy POS tagging and than find the subject out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have two problems, **ID extraction** and **intent detection**.

---

### ID Extraction

If your IDs follow a regular pattern and definitely don't look like English, you can catch them with a regex - if that's possible, that's great since it's very easy to do. If you have a fixed list of product IDs, just check to see if any of them are in the input. If neither of those work then you'll have to get more sophisticated.

Can you get your users to remember a little syntax? If you can request that they write things with a prefix like `id:X26TH` or similar that would make your job easier. You may find the way the [plumber](http://www.mostlymaths.net/2013/04/just-as-mario-using-plan9-plumber.html) in Plan9 works informative.

If you need to work with whatever the users throw at you, you should look into using a **sequence labeller** or **Named Entity Recognition (NER)** system to get IDs. CRFs are probably a good fit for this task; [here's](http://blog.echen.me/2012/01/03/introduction-to-conditional-random-fields/) a good technial introduction, and the New York Times [also used one with success](https://open.blogs.nytimes.com/2015/04/09/extracting-structured-data-from-recipes-using-conditional-random-fields/). Besides being trickier to set up a downside of this is that it will require training data, but there's really no way to avoid that.

---

### Intent Detection

This is usually modelled as a text classification problem. You can find an overview of how to do that [here](https://chatbotslife.com/text-classification-using-algorithms-e4d50dcba45). Here's some training examples from the article:

```py
training_data.append({"class":"greeting", "sentence":"how are you?"})
training_data.append({"class":"greeting", "sentence":"how is your day?"})
training_data.append({"class":"greeting", "sentence":"good day"})
training_data.append({"class":"greeting", "sentence":"how is it going today?"})

training_data.append({"class":"goodbye", "sentence":"have a nice day"})
training_data.append({"class":"goodbye", "sentence":"see you later"})
training_data.append({"class":"goodbye", "sentence":"have a nice day"})
training_data.append({"class":"goodbye", "sentence":"talk to you soon"})

training_data.append({"class":"sandwich", "sentence":"make me a sandwich"})
training_data.append({"class":"sandwich", "sentence":"can you make a sandwich?"})
training_data.append({"class":"sandwich", "sentence":"having a sandwich today?"})
training_data.append({"class":"sandwich", "sentence":"what's for lunch?"})
```

Comment: That blog post was really helpful. Thanks